# Hover id div not working css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to create multi drop menu. so I tried to create the layout first for menu layout and submenu. firstly it work without hover. it show left and right layout with color gray and purple. but it failed to show when I tried to hover.

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.menu {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.sub-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#l-sub-menu {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#r-sub-menu {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  display: none;
}

#l-sub-menu:hover #r-sub-menu {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">a123465</div>
<div class="menu">
  b123456
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div id="l-sub-menu">
    </div>
    <div id="r-sub-menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu">c12456</div>
```

Comment: change this `#l-sub-menu:hover #r-sub-menu` with `#l-sub-menu:hover + #r-sub-menu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong selector...You have to use [**adjacent sibling combinator** `(+)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to achieve your result.

`#l-sub-menu:hover #r-sub-menu`...it will select `#r-sub-menu` inside `#l-sub-menu`

`#l-sub-menu:hover + #r-sub-menu`...it will select `#r-sub-menu` next to `#l-sub-menu`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.menu {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.sub-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#l-sub-menu {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#r-sub-menu {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  display: none;
}

#l-sub-menu:hover+#r-sub-menu {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">a123465</div>
<div class="menu">
  b123456
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div id="l-sub-menu">
    </div>
    <div id="r-sub-menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu">c12456</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much too.

Answer (score 0):

`#l-sub-menu #r-sub-menu {` means

```
<div id="l-sub-menu">
    <div id="r-sub-menu"> </div><-------------Selected
</div>
```

`#l-sub-menu + #r-sub-menu {` means

```
<div id="l-sub-menu"></div>
<div id="r-sub-menu"></div><-----------------Selected
```

**So you must use this:**

```
#l-sub-menu:hover + #r-sub-menu {
```

```css
body {
margin: auto;
}

.menu {
padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
height: 35px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
color: white;
line-height: 35px;
}

.sub-menu {
min-width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}

#l-sub-menu {
float: left;
min-width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: gray;
}

#r-sub-menu {
float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: purple;
display: none;
}

#l-sub-menu:hover + #r-sub-menu {
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">a123465</div>
<div class="menu">
b123456
<div class="sub-menu">
<div id="l-sub-menu">
</div>
<div id="r-sub-menu">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">c12456</div>
```

Comment: Thx you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
min-width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
display: none;
}
```

add "display: none" property to .sub-menu and use hover selector on .menu.